# Execution of Rcpp chunks in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

[The knitr language engines](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_knitr_engines.html) makes it possible to include an Rcpp chunk in your R Markdown document. This works perfectly when knitting the entire document.

However, it doesn't seem to be possible to execute (that is, compile) the Rcpp chunk interactively in RStudio (v. 1.1.364), or am I missing something?

I could keep the C++ code in a separate file and use `sourceCpp` in a chunk, which also works fine. However, for small examples I use in teaching it's more convenient to have everything in one document. I could then use `cppFunction`, but that doesn't give proper syntax highlighting.

I'm either looking for an answer that shows that I, indeed, missed how to interactively compile Rcpp chunks in RStudio, or answers that suggest good practices for i) having all code in one file, and ii) being able to execute chunks interactively.

Comment: If anything that is an issue with your RStudio use, and not with Rcpp.  Have you looked into R Notebooks yet?  They should do it...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, I understand that it's not an Rcpp issue. Notebooks and other R Markdown documents with Rcpp chunks work fine when the entire document is knitted. It's only a question about the possibility of interactively executing Rcpp chunks using e.g. "Run Current Chunk".

Comment: Do you mind changing the tags and maybe add `knitr` (you seem to have a workflow issue) and remove `rcpp` (as there is no misfeature in Rcpp here)?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, done. It wasn't my intention to indicate that Rcpp did anything wrong.